# dynamic dropdown height, can you set max-height to fit content?

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/fuzzalicious/pen/YzYwozv

```
.faq-content {
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-off {
  max-height: 0;
}

.dropdown-on {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

I have an animated dropdown that uses max-height, but I can only get it to work with static height, I would like it work with any content so you don't have to know the height in advance.
Now I'm setting max-height to 1000px which means longer lists would be cut off and short ones take long to animate. Is there any way to use something like max-height: auto or calculate the content height?

Comment: You are already using JS so use JS to dynamically calculate the height of each element

Comment: @TemaniAfif you mean to alter the css with javascript rather then bothering with classes?